# Having a weird issue in JSON // Odd Phenomena

Tags: json, image, lottie

Having an odd problem I've been scratching my head about! We imported JSON Files for images (and it shows the image on Desktop) and on certain phones - for example, when I use Google Chrome on my Google Pixel, same version number and everything - fully up to date, I can see the image, BUT on a Galaxy S23 Ultra, same version in Chrome, I can't see the image. I just see a blank space!

Reloaded multiple times.

Browser versions are both the same.

It's interesting and I'm scratching my head wondering why the universe hates me lol

Compared Browser Versions
Used different browsers, expectation was images would show for S23 Ultra but nope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the annoying CORS Policy.. Figured it out...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).